# Auto-fill the date and time in 2 cells, when the user enters information in an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code which would auto-fill the date in column B once i add value's in column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date & " " & Time = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

what im looking for is to also add the current time to column C.

ok so i found what im looking for but it requires little modification where the date and time are being set.
below is the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
Set A = Range("D:D")
Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Inte
        If r.Value > 0 Then
           r.Offset(0, -3).Value = Date
           r.Offset(0, -3).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
           r.Offset(0, -2).Value = Time
           r.Offset(0, -2).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
        Else
           r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ""
           r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ""
        End If
    Next r
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

to auto-fill column E with date, instead of column A
and auto-fill column F with time, instead of column B

and if possible im trying to have the same process but another cell on the same sheet.

Comment: This code does produce a FALSE outcome as you are entering a boolean test?

Comment: its supposed to provide with the current date in column B and current Time in column C simultaneously once i add value in column A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might look at using SpecialCells to do this in one hit rather than a loop, a simple mod to your code would be:

*one-shot per range area method*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In Inte.Areas
       r.Offset(0, 1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = Date
       r.Offset(0, 2).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = Time
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*initial answer*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString Then r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date 
            If r.Offset(0, 2).Value = vbNullString Then r.Offset(0, 2).Value = Time
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: its returning false, in columns B and C

Comment: it worked, thank you for your its much appreciated, just one last thing, is it possible to have the same code twice, in the same sheet, but with different target column?

i'd have 2 columns which would update their adjacent cells the ("A:A") and another one ("D:D")

Answer (score 0):

if you want to:

- put current Date in `Target` adjacent column blank cells
- put current Time in `Target` adjacent column blank cells adjacent cells

then go like follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target).Address <> Target.Address Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if all target cells aren't in column "A"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Target.Offset(, 1)) = 0 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no blank cells in target adjacent column
    With Target.Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) '<--| reference blank cells in target adjacent column
        .Value = Date '<--| set referenced cells value to the current date
        .Offset(, 1).Value = Time '<--| set referenced cells adjacent ones value to the current time
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

While if you want to:

- put current Date in `Target` adjacent column blank cells
- put current Time in `Target` two columns offset blank cells

then go like follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target).Address <> Target.Address Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if all target cells aren't in column "A"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = Date '<--|  set target adjacent column blank cells  to the current date
    Target.Offset(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = Time '<--|  set target two columns offset blank cells  to the current time
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

where the `On Error Resume Next` is there to avoid two distinct `If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(someRange) Then someRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = someValue` statements

Normally you would avoid `On Error Resume Next` statement and ensure you're handling any possible errors.

But in this case, being it confined to the last two statements of a sub, I think it's a good trade off in favour of code readability without actually loosing its control